# remove content of last occurrence of brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

What will be the JavaScript Regex to remove the content of last occurrence of brackets?

*Hello, this is Mike (keep this) some thing (remove this)*

to

*Hello, this is Mike (keep this) some thing*

Comment: try this `str.replaceAll(/\([^()]*\)[^()]*$/g, "");`

Comment: @codingmonster, can we also remove the space that is coming at the end after 'thing '

Comment: @codingmonster, thanks looking good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
let str  = 'Hello, this is Mike (keep this) some thing (remove this)';
console.log(str.replaceAll(/\s*\([^()]*\)[^()]*$/g, ""));
```